# MSVC Destructors with 2 Arguments

Tags: msvc

I'm reversing a program which I assume was compiled with MSVC. It's seeming like the first entry in each vtable is the class' destructor. However, when I look at the disassembly and decompilation, it seems like the destructors all take a second argument, and that the object's memory is only freed if that second argument is nonnull.

What is the purpose for this second argument? I would think that, if it's a destructor, the class should always be destructed and its memory freed. So why the second argument which could prohibit the memory from being freed up?

Comment: In C++ there is a construct called "placement new operator". It can be used to construct object in pre-allocated area. For example on the stack. In such case when memory was not allocated for the object, destructor cannot released that memory. Please take a look at  "How to delete the memory allocated by placement new ?" on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/placement-new-operator-cpp/ there is nice example. It's possible to call destructor directly like this : "    // No delete : Explicit call to Destructor. 
    pe->~Complex(); "

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about placement new. So, then, a call to `delete object` in the original code might call the destructor with a non-null second argument, while a call to the destructor, say, because the object was on the stack and went out of scope would have a null second argument, and thus not try to deallocate memory which was on the stack. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: This is exactly how I understood usage of that second parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These wrappers are used in classes with virtual destructors to cover two situations:

1. ensure that the correct `operator delete` is called after the object's destruction via `delete pClass;` statement
2. deletion of arrays allocated via `new Class[N]` expression in the `delete [] class_array;` statement to ensure the correct number of items gets deleted using the correct `operator delete` and handle potential exceptions during the process

From [my old article](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23):

> When class has a virtual destructor, compiler generates a helper
>   function - deleting destructor. Its purpose is to make sure that a
>   proper `operator delete` gets called when destructing a class.
>   Pseudo-code for a deleting destructor looks like following:
>
> ```
> virtual void * A::'scalar deleting destructor'(uint flags)
> {
>   this->~A();
>   if (flags&1) A::operator delete(this);
> };
> ```
>
> The address of this function is placed into the vftable instead of the
>   destructor's address. This way, if another class overrides the virtual
>   destructor, `operator delete` of that class will be called. Though in
>   real code `operator delete` gets overriden quite rarely, so usually
>   you see a call to the default delete().
>
> Sometimes compiler can also
>   generate a *vector deleting destructor*. Its code looks like this:
>
> ```
> virtual void * A::'vector deleting destructor'(uint flags)
> {
>   if (flags&2) //destructing a vector
>   {
>     array = ((int*)this)-1; //array size is stored just before the this pointer
>     count = array[0];
>     'eh vector destructor iterator'(this,sizeof(A),count,A::~A);
>     if (flags&1) A::operator delete(array);
>   }
>   else {
>     this->~A();
>     if (flags&1) A::operator delete(this);
>   }
> };
> ```

For more details see also [*C++: Under the Hood*](http://www.openrce.org/articles/files/jangrayhood.pdf) by Jan Gray, one of the main developers of Visual C++.

I also recommend you to make some classes with custom operators new/delete and check the generated code.